# Displaying images from RSS feed

Tags: image, rss, feed

I use NewsRepublic to access feeds. My feed http://www.ukcorporategifts.co.uk/blog/feed is there and the text displays correctly, however I can't get it to show images and inks. Do you know where the issue might lie?

I will be very grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your image links are relative urls (the src part)

```
<img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="/assets/images/promotional-prime-tv-towels.jpg" alt="Promotional Beach Towels" />
```

You should use absolute urls, like http://example.com/assets/images/promotional-prime-tv-towels.jpg

Comment: We've changed it now but the images are still not being shown in the app.

Comment: The feed is probably cached by NewsRepublic. Maybe if you try to make small updates to feed contents, it might be refreshed by the feed reader.